# Adding serial numbers as first column to a CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a text file that has a date followed by temperature values. I am converting it to a `.csv` file with the help of following command:

```
Import-Csv D:\Arduino\sketch_lm35\11-04-17-LM35.txt -Delimiter "`t" |
    Export-Csv D:\Arduino\sketch_lm35\test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

So the generated .csv file will have the date as the first column and temperature as the second column. Now I need to insert a serial number as the first column in the .csv file. How can it be done with PowerShell?

Answer (score 3):

Use [calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) for adding columns to a CSV:

```
Import-Csv ... | Select-Object @{n='Serial';e={...}}, * | Export-Csv ...
```